# why is my bootstrap page here not mobile friendly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

My site is hosted at "nateshmbhat.github.io". I have used mdboostrp's row and col for my dom. But its not mobile friendly (shows lot of background space).

Site : https://nateshmbhat.github.io/ .
Its a static site.

How do i fix it ?

Site code : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/nateshmbhat.github.io

Comment: please leave some comment about the downvotes .

Comment: I did not down vote, but you could provide more details about your problem/what you have done and show us some specific code here, for more accurate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your cards use the class "m-5".

```
<div class="card m-5 hoverable projectCard" style="width: 22rem;">
```

If you want them to be responsive using boostrap the class is "col-md-5".

```
<div class="card col-md-5 hoverable projectCard">
```

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Where did you find `md-5`? The docs don't mention it: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: The bootstrap 4 grid system works as follow https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 2):

Add this tag to the head:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: it still looks like all the cards stick to the right edge of screen and shows only left margin\

Comment: @Nateshbhat, You have set up a width in the line, ```<div class="card m-5 hoverable projectCard" style="width: 22rem;">``` and i think so it was not making the responsive, try to remove the ```width: 22rem``` in mobile devices using media query and so you can get mobile responsive..